# Is it valid to have non-private data members in inner private classes?

Tags: java, oop

I am working in Java and I am having some OOP philosophical problems. An OOP good practice is to make all data members *private* (and *final* if possible) and I agree. However, I think that there are situations where we can violate this rule without losing encapsulation, e.g., a private inner class which is used only for internal purposes, it's data members could be public and no external class could modify it.

To be more specific I am implementing some data structures as part of my preparation for an interview and here is my first attempt to implement a `LinkedList` `Node` class:

```
class Node<T> {
    private T value;
    private Node<T> nextNode;

    public Node(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
        nextNode = null;
    }

    public Node<T> getNext()
    {
        return nextNode;
    }

    public void setNext(Node<T> next)
    {
        nextNode = next;
    }

    public T getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(T v)
    {
        value = v;
    }
}
```

This class is used only in my `LinkedList` class. I think it's too much code for a simple `Node` class, this other implementation would drastically reduce the size of the source code:

```
class Node<T> {
    T value;
    Node<T> next = null;
}
```

I have found that even the Java developers use this practice in the JDK source code, e.g., `Entry` class inside the `HashMap` implementation:

```
static class Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
    final K key;
    V value;
    Entry<K,V> next;
    int hash;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Which makes the code more compact.

Some language like C# or PHP provide ways access data members more naturally, e.g.:

```
public string name
{
    get { return _name;  }
    set { _name = value; }
}
```

But in Java we have to create accessor methods.

In my opinion it's valid to have non-private data members in private internal classes but I am not an OOP expert and I don't want to raise red flags in my interview.

I know that questions asking opinions are usually closed but I really need some points of view from the experts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A private inner class is part of the  implementation of the class, hidden from the outside, so from an OO standpoint you are free to do anything you want. You're not breaking encapsulation in any way.

You can actually declare variables in the inner class as `private` and access them from the containing class without restriction. But if you decide you prefer to use methods to read and write them, up to you. Accessor methods give you more flexibility if you decide to change something, but what needs changing is limited to the containing class.